# How to get the output of php and pass this output to pure html page?

Tags: php, html

This is a critical scenario.I have 2 pages such as

```
output.php has dynamic table data with style which is get from excel.

<?php
ob_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


    /* EXCEL TABLE */

    $inputFileName2 = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Monthly-EDM\Action_items.xlsx';


    try {
        $objPHPExcel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName2);

    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName2, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    /* Open an Excel & count */
    $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel1->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

    $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet); // Here get total count of row in that Excel sheet


    $file = fopen($inputFileName2, "r");
    fclose($file);

      echo '<table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">';
     echo '<tr>';
                echo '</td>';   

             /* <th> code here */
                            echo '</td>';
                       echo ' </tr>';
                        echo ' <!-- Header blue row - end -->';


                    echo '<style>.shiva:nth-child(odd)      { background-color:#b9b8bb; }</style>';
                    echo '<style>.shiva:nth-child(even) { background-color:#e5e8e8; }</style>'; 

    for ($i = 2; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++) {

        $_SESSION["a"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);

        $_SESSION["b"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);

        $_SESSION["c"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);

        $_SESSION["d"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]);

        $_SESSION["e"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]);

        $_SESSION["f"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["F"]);

        $_SESSION["g"] = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["G"]);

             echo ' <tr>';
              echo '<td>';

          echo '</td>';
             echo ' </tr>';

   }
             echo '<!-- table content - end --> ';
             echo '</table>';
             echo '</td>';
             echo ' </tr>';
             echo '</table>';

?>

    get.html (I want to get the output of output.php here)
```

[Click to view the result of the output.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd1SM.jpg)

How to get the output of output.php and pass this output to get.html page and show the output.Is this possible to access the php output from html page??
Thanks in advance.Please help me to fix it.

Comment: I believe the best way is for the output of `output.php` to be JSON and then `get.html` could parse it and display in using the layout using either jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code to avoid any guessing

Comment: Hi,I have given the code of output.php page.can u help me to pass this output to pure html page(get.html).Thanks.refer the link above "Click to view the result of the output.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Here is one solution (this solution assumes you are using Apache)

Create a `.htaccess` file at the root of your site. Put this in the `.htaccess` file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

This file will make Apache parse `.html` files as PHP. Then in your `get.html` file, put this code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body><?php include('path/to/output.php'); ?></body>
</html>
```

If you view the `get.html` file in your browser, you will see the output of `output.php`

#### Here is an alternative solution using Javascript and AJAX:

Put the following code in your `get.html` file. This will make an ajax request to your `output.php` file and put the response in a `<div id="output"></div>`.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="output"></div>
        <script>
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', 'output.php', true);
            
            request.onload = function() {
                if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = request.responseText;
                } else {
                    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
                }
            };
            
            request.onerror = function() {
                // There was a connection error of some sort
            };
            
            request.send();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: WOW..Thank you so much...Its working Fine now..Thanks for your support.You are GREAT and rocking developer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, if this is what you mean. But if you make a file (foo.php) and put it in the same directory as where `output.php` is, and then add this to foo.php:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("output.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("output.php"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Then that should print the content of `output.php` in your browser, as HTML (if you go to `/foo.php` in the browser).

Is that it?

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I need to save the output in foo.html(pure html with this extension).Any suggestion??